# How to get VBA Macro to run continuously in the background?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to monitor a value and get an email notifications when certain conditions are met. I have a macro like so:

```
Do While True

    Worksheet.Calculate

    If Value > 10 Then
        SendEmail
    End If

    Sleep 60*CLng(1000)

Loop
```

However, when I run this, it clogs up the entire program and will turn unresponsive if I try to do anything.

Is there anyway to accomplish this but have it run in the background or at least not crash the program?

What I was doing before was using VBScript to open a not-visible spreadsheet and the VBScript ran continuously in the background monitoring the condition and worked fine, but my client really wants a GUI and for it to be in the program itself.

Any thoughts?

Comment: If you need to monitor a cell's value than you don't need to continuously run a code, but use the worksheet's change event.

Comment: @MátéJuhász I don't think the value will change on its own. It needs to be prompted to. I'll update the sample code. Can I still use worksheet's change event?

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/79144-automatically-update-time-date.html, it might be useful for you.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use the `Application.OnTime` method to schedule code that will run in one minute.

Your code will look something like this (Untested):

```
Sub CreateNewSchedule()
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=DateAdd("n", 1, Now), Procedure:="macro_name", Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub macro_name()

    If Value > 10 Then
        SendEmail
    Else
        CreateNewSchedule
    End If

End Sub
```

You might want to store the time of the next schedule in a global variable so that the `Workbook_BeforeClose` event can cancel the next schedule. Otherwise Excel will re-open the workbook.

```
Public nextScheduledTime As Date

Sub CreateNewSchedule()
    nextScheduledTime  = DateAdd("n", 1, Now)
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=nextScheduledTime , Procedure:="macro_name", Schedule:=True
End Sub

Sub macro_name()

    If Value > 10 Then
        SendEmail
    Else
        CreateNewSchedule
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
On Error Resume Next
    Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=nextScheduledTime, Procedure:="macro_name", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

You can then continue to use Excel between the scheduled times.

Comment: Thank you. Your `CreateNewSchedule` function works perfectly. I didn't know about that feature

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to specifically process the application event stack with a [DoEvents](https://support.office.com/en-ca/article/DoEvents-Function-7af41eca-88e0-470d-adaf-0b3d4c2575b0) call. This allows user interactions with the spreadsheet to occur, where normally the macro would take precedence. You code would look something like:

```
Do While True

    If Value > 10 Then
        SendEmail
    End If

    Sleep 60*CLng(1000)

    DoEvents
Loop
```

You could also construct a GUI with HTA if you wanted to remain with VBScript.

Comment: Another way would be to set a macro to run whenever the spreadsheet changes.

Comment: Yes, that's a better solution to be honest, because you'll still get some application lock-up here as a result of the sleep command, I think. I suggest you post it as an answer to this question - I'd upvote it :-). The only problem would come if no user interaction occurred, but a mail needed to be sent. In that case, if the sleep command isn't actually timing something, you could just reduce it to 33ms or something un-noticable.

Comment: @HolmesIV, see my response in the comments above.