# Excel 2010 VBA - Continually Looking In Folder for File to Process?

Tags: excel, file, excel-2010, vba

I have a need to build a macro in Excel 2010 that basically runs continually (started by button or stopped by button) that looks into a file folder.  If a file is created there and named a certain way then the macro opens it and processes the data inside.  The file is then closed and deleted.  The macro then continues on to watch the file folder for more files to process

Is this a reasonable / doable macro that I could create in Excel with VBA?  Can VBA continually run without issues?

Best Regards
Andy

Comment: Yes it is feasible with an `Application.OnTime` loop. Try it :)

Comment: The short answers to your questions are yes and yes. This isn't a free code-writing service though. We're happy to help you with issues you've run into with code you've already written. I would suggest looking into the `Application.OnTime` [method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-ontime-method-excel).

Comment: Thanks for the advice guys!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your program continuously pulling changing data from the Excel sheet? If not, I would advise creating the program in another language and running in a continuous loop containing your code and the sleep() function. If so, then I would recommend using the worksheet change event, and you cannot edit the worksheet while a macro is running(even if you use the sleep/wait command in VBA)

This link might also prove helpful: [How to get VBA Macro to run continuously in the background?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31210921/how-to-get-vba-macro-to-run-continuously-in-the-background)

Answer (score 0):

see this thread for some ideas:

https://superuser.com/questions/226828/how-to-monitor-a-folder-and-trigger-a-command-line-action-when-a-file-is-created

the first answer probably will do it, just trigger the excel macro you want from that. You can get as fancy as you want with the execution. The application.ontime function only works if excel is open, I believe.

What you want is to find a way to monitor the folder constantly.